# Building/Running Xamarin Conference app fails

Tags: xamarin

I've just downloaded the Xamarin conference demo code at https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-conference, using the latest 6.3 Xamarin Studio Community on Mac osx (10.12), but, it fails with "namespace name 'Client' does not exist in namespace 'Conference'", and other errors.

Shouldn't this code at least build/compile with the "stable" release of Xamarin?  I'm also getting strange warnings on the load of the project "Unknown solution type".

I've attached screenshots also.

[image]
[image]

Not sure where to start with these, I would expect the project to load/build.

Comment: Those are netstandard2.0 projects and from the fact that a iOS 10.x simulator is showing in your VS4M interface, I would say you are on an OLD version of Visual Studio. You will need to update to the latest version (Xcode also)

Comment: You shouldn't be using Xamarin Studio anymore and instead be using the latest Visual Studio for Mac, which the project builds and runs fine on. I tried it on my old Xamarin Studio installation and I'm seeing the same errors you are when trying to build in it.

Comment: Nick/Sushi: yes, both correct, I updated to Visual Studio for Mac, it's working now, thanks!